# How to create a 2D background with "noise" in it? Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, background

I was browsing Google Images for 2D games with shadows and came across this image here:

---

[image: Game Image]

***Image taken from [iaco79](https://iaco79.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/lights-and-shadows-for-2d-worlds/) and is NOT MY WORK***

---

Now I really like this look and I think a lot of it is due to the gradient (which I think I can manage) and the noise in the background. In my game a I have script which takes 5 colors and blends them together for the main camera's background color at different rates the as the game goes on, giving me a cool color changing background. Is there a way I could add the what they have on this game to make the background not a simple solid color? Also my camera moves so would it be possible to make this noise not, so it looks like its part of the world and not the background? Any tips or ideas is greatly appreciated!

### Edit

I've been doing a lot more research and came across [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html). In my version of Unity I don't have / I can't find the Image Effects scripts. I looked on the Unity Asset store but everything there costed a lot. I'd like to keep the spending on this game at a minimum and for me, that is way to much to pay if I don't know if its even going to work. Plus I noticed that they all have a lot of features, which is good, but my game might only use 2 (noise and the backed edges) of the the 20+ other ones which will just take up space.

Comment: I'd recommend you look into shaders, and perlin noise. You can also pass the camera position into the noise function to move get the effect of global noise.

Comment: @Iggy Thanks, I've looked into it and shades seem to be one of the more complex things in Unity. I just started with Unity so I'd probably give up. Is there a way I could overlay an image with good frame rate? If sharers are the best way to get then I will diffidently give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

So after a day of research I came across [Post Processing Stack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/post-processing-stack-83912), thanks to Iggy's comment, which did mostly everything I needed, and I didn't have to write any shader code. I used the Vintage and the Grain effects and got a similar look to the image that I am very happy with.